# How to get full pah of image using html sothat i can use this path into jsp

Tags: html, jsp

i am using html and Java Server Pages to insert image into  database.
i need full path of image using html as simple as possible,
so that i can retrieve this path in Java Server Pages program and can insert into database.

Comment: Alternatively,  you can upload image to /Upload folder and save the file name in database and can retrieve file name to show images in <img/> tag !

Comment: Please clarify. What do you want to do? Where is the image stored? On the client? On the server? WHat would you like the user of your application to be able to do?

Comment: are you will upload a pic from client and store it to the server database?

Comment: that's problem which i have while uploading....